# Form Errors shown after refreshing the page

Tags: forms, 8

I have a custom form, which is rendered in a custom block in drupal 8. Now the problem is when I place some form validation code on the form in validate function it works well but the error message is shown after page refresh. I think this issue is related to caching. when I render that form using routing the error message shows.the problem is when the form is rendered in block.

Comment: there is no error message. the error message is my custom message.it only displayed after I refresh the page or move to different page after submitting the form

Comment: Try adding a `messages` element to your block. It is the render element that prints system messages.

Comment: Please check this "https://www.drupal.org/node/2773333" patch. Hope this will help you .